# Laravel : Prompt before deleting a user

Tags: laravel, laravel-4, laravel-blade

I am successfully deleting records in my table using the code below. My only problem, I want it to prompt the user to confirm the action before deleting.

```
{{link_to_route('individualprofiles.edit', 'Edit', array($ip->id))}}
{{Form::open(array( 'route' => array( 'individualprofiles.destroy', $ip->id ), 'method' => 'delete', 'style' => 'display:inline'))}}
     {{Form::submit('D', array('class' => 'btn btn-danger'))}}
{{Form::close()}}
```

Comment: [Check this](http://heera.it/bootstrap-3-delete-confirm-dialog).

Comment: @The Alpha May be you just draft a quick answer so I can accept that. Your  link worked for me. But I think its very important for you to mention that changing button type to button instead is crucial for it to work on some versions of Bootstrap. I knew about after reading your comment section.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

### You may try something like this:

**STEP – 1**

First of all, you need to add `bootstrap.css` file using a link tag, `jQuery` and `bootstrap.js` file using a script tag in your head section of your web page. On bootstrap’s website, you would find details about this. It’s also possible to build a customized file with selected components from here if you don’t want to use full bootstrap framework.

**STEP – 2**

Add following html code in a file and save it as a separate file, for example `delete_confirm.php`

```
<!-- Modal Dialog -->
<div class="modal fade" id="confirmDelete" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="confirmDeleteLabel" aria-hidden="true">
  <div class="modal-dialog">
    <div class="modal-content">
      <div class="modal-header">
        <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-hidden="true">&times;</button>
        <h4 class="modal-title">Delete Parmanently</h4>
      </div>
      <div class="modal-body">
        <p>Are you sure about this ?</p>
      </div>
      <div class="modal-footer">
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" data-dismiss="modal">Cancel</button>
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-danger" id="confirm">Delete</button>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Also, paste following JavaScript code in the same file as well

```
<!-- Dialog show event handler -->
  $('#confirmDelete').on('show.bs.modal', function (e) {
      $message = $(e.relatedTarget).attr('data-message');
      $(this).find('.modal-body p').text($message);
      $title = $(e.relatedTarget).attr('data-title');
      $(this).find('.modal-title').text($title);

      // Pass form reference to modal for submission on yes/ok
      var form = $(e.relatedTarget).closest('form');
      $(this).find('.modal-footer #confirm').data('form', form);
  });

  <!-- Form confirm (yes/ok) handler, submits form -->
  $('#confirmDelete').find('.modal-footer #confirm').on('click', function(){
      $(this).data('form').submit();
  });
```

**STEP – 3**

Now, in any page where you want to use this confirm modal dialog, just include it using `require_once` or `include_once` like:

```
// other code
require_once('delete_confirm.php');
```

**STEP – 4**

To build a delete action button you may use something like this:

```
<form method="POST" action="http://example.com/admin/user/delete/12" accept-charset="UTF-8" style="display:inline">
    <button class="btn btn-xs btn-danger" type="button" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#confirmDelete" data-title="Delete User" data-message="Are you sure you want to delete this user ?">
        <i class="glyphicon glyphicon-trash"></i> Delete
    </button>
</form>
```

For more information [check this article](http://heera.it/bootstrap-3-delete-confirm-dialog#.VF_sffmUeSo)

Answer (score 3):

By using `'onsubmit' => "return confirm('Are you sure you want to delete?')"` inside `Form::open`.

```
{{Form::open(array( 
    'route' => array( 'individualprofiles.destroy', $ip->id ), 
    'method' => 'delete', 
    'style' => 'display:inline',
    'onsubmit' => "return confirm('Are you sure you want to delete?')",
))}}
     {{Form::submit('D', array('class' => 'btn btn-danger'))}}
{{Form::close()}}
```

Answer (score 1):

Add an ID or class to your form, and use javascript to catch the forms submit action.  Prompt the user, and if they confirm, use javascript to submit the form.

Another way to do this without javascript is to create a view that prompts the user to confirm the delete.  Your delete button becomes a link to the confirm page, and the confirm page would contain this form.